# Continuous function taking given values and bounded by a certain constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Given $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ and $t_1,...,t_n\in [a,b]$ (where $t_i$'s are distinct) and $a_1,...,a_n\in \mathbb{C}$ how to define a complex-valued continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$ such that $f(t_i)=a_i$ for each $1\leq i\leq n$ and $\max_{t\in [a,b]}|f(t)|\leq \max_{1\leq i\leq n}|a_i|$ ?

It is easy to define such a real-valued continuous function (with that conditions), so I tried to use real-valued ones as the real and imaginary parts of the desired function, but I ran into some scaling problems while trying to satisfy given conditions.
I think it seems a subtle task to define a complex-valued one. Could anybody give a clue/hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if $t_i$'s are all the same and $a_i$' are distinct?

Comment: Is the problem you put complete? Where have you arrived at?

Comment: No difference between real and complex case (when $t_i$'s are distinct) . Just make $f$ piece-wise linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each interval $[t_i, t_{i+1}]$, you can define the function as $$f(x) = a_{i+1}\frac{x-t_i}{t_{i+1}-t_i} + a_i\frac{t_{i+1} - x}{t_{i+1}-t_i}$$ i.e. the linear interpolation between the two complex points.

Comment: I think you mean $f(x)=a_{i+1}\frac{x-t_i}{t_{i+1}-t_i}+a_i\frac{t_{i+1}-x}{t_{i+1}-t_i}$

Comment: But still I cannot see why $\max_{x\in [a,b]}|f(x)|\leq \max_{1\leq i\leq n}|a_i|$

Comment: @serenus On every interval $[t_i, t_{i+1}]$ the value of $f$ is a convex combination of $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$, i.e. $f(x) = \alpha a_i + (1-\alpha) a_{i+1}$ for some $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ (which depends on $x$ in an unimportant way). Thus $$|f(x)| \leqslant \alpha |a_i| + (1-\alpha) |a_{i+1}| \leqslant \max \{ |a_i|, |a_{i+1}| \}.$$

Comment: @Adayah You are right, this is the argument I was needed. Btw, is my formula correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.